# how to get all DOM elements which are 5 levels far from the root element

Tags: javascript

How do you build a JS method that finds the n'th level elements. so for example: all level 2: elements:

```
<div>
   <div>
      <div>
          find me (level 2)
      </div>
      <p>
          find me too(level 2)
      </p>
   </div>
   <div>
      not me (level 1)
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to tell us what you tried. People are not writing code for you, they guide you to the right direction

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```js
const level2 = document.querySelectorAll('body > * > * > *');

console.log(level2);
```

```html
<div>
   <div>
      <div>
          find me (level 2)
      </div>
      <p>
          find me too(level 2)
      </p>
   </div>
   <div>
      not me (level 1)
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

```js
// creating a named function, that takes the level as an argument
// (though has a default level of 0 specified):
function nthLevelElements(level = 0) {
  // here we define the selector, first we have the `:root` (html)
  // element and concatenate that with the results of:
  // a new Array, of length equal to the parsed (as base 10) integer
  // supplied, if parseInt() returns NaN then instead we default to 1:
  let selector = ':root ' + new Array(parseInt(level, 10) || 1)

// we fill the created Array with ' > * '; this selector selects
// direct children, of all element types, of the previous element:
.fill(' > * ')
  // we remove the first Array element (since our first level in the
  // selector is ':root':
  .slice(1)
  // we join the retained Array elements together using
  // Array.prototype.join() and pass an empty String:
  .join('');

// here we return the elements found as an Array:
return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
}

// we call the function, passing 5 as the argument:
nthLevelElements(5)
  // and iterate over the returned Array of elements
  // using Array.prototype.forEach() along with a
  // simple Arrow function to demonstrate which elements
  // were found:
  .forEach(el => el.classList.add('found'));
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.found {
  background-color: #f90;
}

1
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      find me (level 2)
    </div>
    <p>
      find me too(level 2)
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    not me (level 1)
  </div>
</div>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 3
        <div>in a wrapped &lt;div&gt;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<ol>
  <li><span>span 1</span></li>
  <li><span>span 2</span></li>
  <li><span>span 3</span></li>
  <li><span>span 4</span></li>
  <li><span>span 5</span></li>
</ol>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/stnjqfva/).

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: Thank you very much. helped me alot (;

Answer (score 0):

The following code finds nodes (elements, text nodes, etc.) that are `n` levels away from a given element.

```js
function finder(levels, startEl) {
  const result = [];
  const stack = [
    [startEl, levels]
  ];

  while (stack.length) {
    const [el, elLevel] = stack.pop();
    if (elLevel === 1) {
      if (el.childNodes.length) {
        result.push(...el.childNodes);
      }
      continue;
    }
    if (el.children.length === 0) {
      continue;
    }
    const childLevel = elLevel - 1;
    const childrenWithLevel = Array.from(el.children)
      .map(el => [el, childLevel]);

    stack.push(...childrenWithLevel);
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(
  finder(5, document.documentElement)
)
```

```html
<div>
   <div>
      <div>
          find me (level 2)
      </div>
      <p>
          find me too(level 2)
      </p>
   </div>
   <div>
      not me (level 1)
   </div>
</div>
```